# Add the "view all" link to the sidebar list of communities on your own profile

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, network-profile

When viewing someone else's profile, there's a list of their top few sites on the side. This includes a "view all" link to the network profile:

[image: A screenshot showing the communities list on the sidebar, with the "view all" link circled with a red freehand circle]

When viewing your own profile, though, this link is replaced with an "edit" link:

[image: A screenshot of the view for your own profile, with no "view all" link]

Ever since this was redesigned about a year ago, this has been tripping me up. The previous interface, before the redesign, had a link to the network profile there even for your own profile, and I'd regularly use that when I need to visit the accounts tab on my own network profile.
It's been over a year since that page was redesigned, and I'm still tripping over this, so it'd be nice if that functionality was restored for those of us used to the old behavior and to be consistent with the view on other users.

I'd be in favor of either putting the "view all" link where "edit" is currently, and moving "edit" to the blank space in the middle, although I'd also be fine with the other way around.

Comment: Well we have direct link in the Activity tab, there it's called "accounts" instead of "Communities" but leads to the same place. Inconsistency is a major issue in SE.

Comment: There's also a general "Network profile" link at the top-right of anyone's profile page (any tab).